# Como apagar dados do banco de dados no android studio?

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Tenho uma aplicação na qual quando o usuário se loga a primeira vez, eu guardo o `Token` e `NIU`, ai a próxima vez que ele acessar o aplicativo, ele já entra diretamente na `Webview` utilizando esse `token e NIU` que estão no banco. Porém eu preciso apagar esses dados quando o usuário clicar no botão "Sair" na `webview`. Já tenho um tratamento para esse botão (sair), posso inserir o tratamento de apagar os dados do banco aqui também, como fazer?

MÉTODO BT_SAIR:

```
     private void SairWV(){
     Intent intent = new Intent(Webview.this, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();
```

MÉTODO INSERIR NO BANCO:

```
    public long insere (Token token){
    dao = new BancoDeDados(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dao.getWritableDatabase(); 
    dao.onCreate(db);
    ContentValues dados = pegaDadosDoAcesso(token); 
    long inserir = db.insert(NOMETABELA, null, dados);
    db.close();
    Log.i(NOMETABELA, inserir + "");
    return inserir;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra deletar no seu banco de dados voce segue +- a mesma ideia que voce ja esta usando:

```
db.delete(TABELA, CHAVE + "=" + chave, null)
```

Onde `TABELA` é a tabela que você quer realizar o Delete, `CHAVE` é o identificador que vc usa pra aquela linha que quer deletar (seja uma chave primaria, o nome, uma data, o que quiser) e `chave` é o valor a ser comparado pra realizar o delete.

Isso retorna o numero de linhas que foram deletadas, entao voce pode sempre testar se sao > 0 pra ver se deletou mesmo.

Vale a pena dar uma conferida na [documentacao](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html):

Answer (score 2):

Para deletar todos os dados utilize:

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + NOMETABELA);
```

Para apagar apenas uma linha da tabela:

```
db.delete(NOMETABELA, "NOMECAMPO" + "='" + VALOR + "'", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo:

```
   private void SairWV(){

        dao = new BancoDeDados(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dao.getWritableDatabase();
        /** irá remover todos os registros **/
         db.execSQL(String.format("DELETE FROM %s", NOMETABELA));
        /**
         * Quando se usa DELETE TABLE
         para excluir todos os registros,
         recomenda-se usar o comando VACUUM para
         limpar o espaço não utilizado.
         **/
        db.execSQL("VACUUM");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Webview.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

[fonte](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_truncate_table.htm)